# What does "this" mean in this revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript

```
var abc=(function(){

     var self=this;

     return {
        self:self
     }             


})();
```

When doing `abc.self` I get `undefined` what does `this` happen to be in this context.

Comment: `abc.self` works just fine for me, and `this` is the global scope as the IIFE doesn't have a special scope-

Comment: When I do `abc.self` I get the `window` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have can be simplified for the purpose of the explanation in

```
(function(){ console.log(this) })();
```

Your expression (in the first set of parenthesis) defines a function. You then call this function without context (the `this`). This construct is called an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). As you don't pass a context, the behavior depends whether it is called in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or not :

- In non strict mode, you would have the global object (`window` in a browser, `global` in node).
- In strict mode, a missing context of a function call isn't replaced, it's `undefined`.

As you get `undefined`, I guess you're in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). You probably have   `"use strict";` at the start of the file or in an enclosing function.

If you wanted to pass a context, you might for example have done

```
(function(){ console.log(this) }).call(someobject);
```

Comment: Yes i was in strict mode .but i not able to  understand the statment."In strict mode, a missing context of a function call isn't replaced."

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current object. In your condition `this` will be `window`, and as you're trying to get the value `abc.self`, you need to use like this:

```
this.self = this;
```

Now, only you can get the value:

```
var xyz = new abc();
xyz.self
```

---

But to note, you cannot use abc as the constructor like above code because you are using the closure.

Answer (score 1):

in that "root scope" `this` is `window`

and

```
console.log(abc.self);
```

results for me  in

```
Window {top: Window, window: Window, ...}
```